# Creation of init cloud-based VMs(proxmox and terraform)

Tags: terraform, virtual-machine, proxmox

I want to create 3 VMs (with terraform in proxmox) each with their configuration (ram / cpu / disk) and I want to know if I have created a template (to be cloned later in the terraform file) of a size to give prevents others from having a different configuration

example if I put a vm (1cpu / 2 g ram / 10 G disk) and convert it to templete
[I can't or i can] use it to deploy a VMs (3 cpu and 8G ram and 50 G disk)

if yes how i can do it , thanks for ur help .

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please see my repo:
https://github.com/redhug1/R710

and my notes/documents within may have the answers to your question (and a lot more beside):

17 - R710 Proxmox Ubuntu cloud-init image - Terraform - Ansible

18 - R710 Proxmox - Samba shares for W10 and W10 hosts file for WSL

19 - R710 Proxmox Terraform VMs with different - CPU count - RAM and Disks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).